# How to validate external object data?

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, externalobjects

**Requirement -** When user enters a value in a field(Example__c) then it needs to be validated against an external object and only if the value matches then only we save the changes.

**Tried so far -** Initially I was using an apex trigger but while developing it came across the fact that Apex Trigger cannot refer an external object, but we can use lightning flow instead.

**Problem -** I came across this help document:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_asynchronous_path.htm&release=234&type=5

1. Since my update is happening for the same record, I should go for before save option but in document they mentioned about after save.
2. Validating against external table needs to be in asynchronous path whereas my requirement is synchronous if I am not wrong.

Need suggestions that what method or process I should follow to handle these issues.

Comment: Take a look at [Data Integration](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration), [Record-Triggered Automation](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/trigger-automation) and [Building Forms](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/build-forms) decision guides. Collectively, these 3 guides answer your question.

Comment: @identigral - Thanks for the documents. However I still cannot put the puzzle pieces in proper place. Can you please guide me more on this?

Comment: You're asking a broad question, so here's a broad answer: you're going to have rethink your solution in asynchronous terms or use another technology stack.

Comment: @identigral - Thanks for the comments. Now I got more clarity on the use case.